# primeNg input controls context menu paste - ngModel

Tags: angular, primeng

I`m using primeNg input controls (p-spinner, p-calendar). Unfortunately the [(ngModel)]=”value” binding does not fire when I select the paste option from the context menu by mouse. Even if I click out of the control the lost focus does not take into account.
The ctrl+v keyboard operation is fine but the mouse/context menu option would be the more important.
Please help.
My current version:
 "primeng": "^4.1.3",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calendar input field looks like:

```
<input #inputfield 
       type="text" 
       [attr.id]="inputId" 
       [attr.name]="name" 
       [attr.required]="required" 
       [value]="inputFieldValue" 
       (focus)="onInputFocus($event)" 
       (keydown)="onInputKeydown($event)" 
       (click)="datepickerClick=true" 
       (blur)="onInputBlur($event)"
       [readonly]="readonlyInput" 
       (input)="onUserInput($event)" 
       [ngStyle]="inputStyle" 
       [class]="inputStyleClass" 
       [placeholder]="placeholder||''" 
       [disabled]="disabled" 
       [attr.tabindex]="tabindex"
       [ngClass]="'ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all'">
```

when you copy from contextual menu `(keydown)="onInputKeydown($event)"` is triggered:

```
onInputKeydown(event) {
  this.isKeydown = true;
  if(event.keyCode === 9) {
    this.overlayVisible = false;
  }
}
```

and then `(input)="onUserInput($event)"`

```
onUserInput(event) {
  // IE 11 Workaround for input placeholder : https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2026
  if(!this.isKeydown) {
    return;
  }
  this.isKeydown = false;

  let val = event.target.value;   
  try {
    let value = this.parseValueFromString(val);
    this.updateModel(value);
    this.updateUI();
  } 
  catch(err) {
    //invalid date
    this.updateModel(null);
  }

  this.filled = val != null && val.length;
  this.onInput.emit(event);
}
```

it looks like *IE 11 Workaround* causes additional problems with none-keyboard interactions (like paste via right click). So, as work around set `this.isKeydown = true;` on input paste event.

1. Import Calendar and ViewChild:

   ```
   import { Component, NgModule, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
   import { CalendarModule, Calendar } from 'primeng/primeng';
   ```
2. get p calendar reference:
   HTML:

   ```
   <p-calendar #calendarRef [(ngModel)]="value"></p-calendar>
   ```

   TS file:

   ```
   @ViewChild('calendarRef') calendarRef: Calendar;
   ```
3. register paste listener in `ngAfterViewInit` hook:

   ```
   ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.calendarRef.inputfieldViewChild.nativeElement.onpaste = (e) {
       this.calendarRef.isKeydown = true;
     }
   }
   ```

it should work now,

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/SSI4XDxGtu1O59DJZfd4?p=preview

**UPDATE FOR SPINNER**

1. add spinner reference as `@ViewChild`
2. register `onpaste` listener on spinner reference

   ```
   export class App implements OnAfterViewInit {
     @ViewChild('calendarRef') calendarRef: Calendar;
     @ViewChild('spinnerRef') spinnerRef: Spinner;

     value: Date;

     ngAfterViewInit() {
       this.calendarRef.inputfieldViewChild.nativeElement.onpaste = (e) {
         this.calendarRef.isKeydown = true;
       }

       this.spinnerRef.el.nativeElement.onpaste = (event) {
         setTimeout(_ => {
           this.spinnerRef.onInput(event, event.target.value);
         });
       }
     }
   }
   ```

   [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/SSI4XDxGtu1O59DJZfd4?p=preview) also updated

Reference to `onInput()` function: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/spinner/spinner.ts#L201

Comment: This helps with p-calendar but as concerning the p-spinner I still have no idea.

Comment: Here there is no ViewChild handle for the input element: #in

Comment: Even if we would access the input element via spinner.el.nativeElement.children['0'].children['0'] - the implementation is different

Comment: please update my plunker or create a new one (or share your code in some other way) and I will try to help

Comment: I updated my answer and plunker with p-spinner solution

Comment: Excellent! This solution gave me new perspectives.